# Two same strings aren't equal

Tags: javascript

I have 2 equal strings, and when I'm doing a console.log() to know if they are equal, I do this:

```
console.log("message = " + document.getElementsByClassName("hud-chat-message")[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML + " type = " + typeof document.getElementsByClassName("hud-chat-message")[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML)
            console.log("chatbotname = " + Ultimate.bots[name].chatBotName + " type = " + typeof Ultimate.bots[name].chatBotName)
            console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("hud-chat-message")[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML == Ultimate.bots[name].chatBotName)
```

And then it says that:

```
message = <strong>Leaderboard on Discord</strong><small> (leaderboard!)</small><span class="botTagRegular botTag bot">BOT</span> type = string
VM3681:229 chatbotname = <strong>Leaderboard on Discord</strong><small> (leaderboard!)</small><span class='botTagRegular botTag bot'>BOT</span> type = string
VM3681:230 false
```

Two strings are of the same type and are equals, but it says `false`, its not equal... Why? What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: They are not the same. One uses double quotes, the other uses single quotes.

Comment: One of them uses `'` and the other uses `"`.

Comment: There might be some additional white characters that you can't see. Try checking length of both strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `<span class="botTagRegular botTag bot">` is not equal to `<span class='botTagRegular botTag bot'>` because `'` and `"` are different symbols

Comment: Oh, ok! But aren't " ' and ` equal?

Comment: they may have the same effect but no, they are not the same character.

Comment: why downvote a correct answer? because you don't like the question?

Comment: I upvoted, but it says i need 15 reputation... It's not me

Comment: And I can't accept it either, I need to wait

Comment: @Demo people that didn't like your question were downvoting. No worries

Comment: You can improve your answer by noting that `"` is not equal to `'`